# How to format the extrayear field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In author-year citation/bibliography styles, multiple publications by the same author in the same year are formatted with a lowercase letter after the year: *Smith 2011a ... Smith 2011b* etc.

In `biblatex` this works fine with numeric dates, but fails with non-numeric dates like "in progress".  (The `natbib` style I use  handles these cases correctly by putting parentheses around the letter if the year field is non-numeric.)  How do I do the same thing in `biblatex`?  So the expected output is:

Smith, 2011a
Smith, 2011b

Smith, in progress(a)
Smith, in progress(b)

Sample file and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,labelyear=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}
\cite{test1,test2}
\printbibliography
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@unpublished{test1,
    Author = {John Smith},
    Date-Added = {2011-02-21 13:41:09 -0500},
    Date-Modified = {2011-02-21 13:42:02 -0500},
    Note = {ms. MSU},
    Title = {A great paper in progress},
    Year = {in progress}}

@unpublished{test2,
    Author = {John Smith},
    Date-Added = {2011-02-21 13:42:09 -0500},
    Date-Modified = {2011-02-21 13:42:46 -0500},
    Note = {ms. MSU},
    Title = {Another great paper in progress},
    Year = {in progress}}
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: Good question. :-) Note that you don't need to set `labelyear=true`, as this is the default for the `authoryear` style.

Comment: @lockstep So it is.  I wonder if it was always so; as biblatex evolved, my code probably hasn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a somewhat cruel hack, but here we go. Add the following to your preamble (EDIT: Should have scanned the manual more thoroughly -- `\iffieldnums` seems to be the correct test, see p. 148--149):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}{%
    \mknumalph{#1}%
  }{%
    \mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

UPDATE: I have submitted a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3201287&group_id=244752&atid=1126006) at SourceForge.net: biblatex.

UPDATE: The feature request is now pending. Philipp Lehman, author of biblatex, commented:

> I'll add that even though I'm not
>   entirely convinced that this is the
>   way to deal with work in progress. I'd
>   rather recommend putting "in progress"
>   in the "pubstate" field and set a
>   label in the "label" field.

UPDATE: This feature has been implemented in biblatex v1.3 (released March 14th, 2011).

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think this is a cruel hack? (It probably should be the default, but that's another issue.) Or was your cruel hack before you read the manual and edited your answer?

Comment: @Alan: Exactly.

Comment: @Alan: If my solution shapes up as robust, I will submit a feature request at `sourceforge.biblatex`. The current state can only be an oversight.