# biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

The standard `authoryear` style in `biblatex` puts parentheses around the year in the bibliography and no parentheses around in text citation years:

> - Smith 2011 shows ... (citation)
> - Smith, Joe (2011) ... (bibliography)

Is there a (simple) way to turn these into:

> - Smith (2011) shows ... (citation)
> - Smith, Joe. 2011. ... (bibliography)

Comment: The latest version of this question with changes for current versions of `biblatex` is now at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks to egreg's great [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705/510) to [biblatex: Is it possible to patch macros created with \newbibmacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40703/biblatex-is-it-possible-to-patch-macros-created-with-newbibmacro), the solution to the present question is easy: Use the new `\patchbibmacro` command to selectively change the definition of the `date+extradate` bibmacro *however this definition looks like in the first place* (provided some common patterns are present).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% By courtesy of Enrico Gregorio (egreg)
\makeatletter
\def\act@on@bibmacro#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
}
\def\patchbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\patchcmd}
\def\pretobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\pretocmd}
\def\apptobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\apptocmd}
\def\showbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\show}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\patchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Things are even easier with egreg's [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you know, this is pretty easy (and thanks!), but it's absolutely hilarious to me that such a common formatting requirement isn't provided for already, and that the solution seems to be low-level hax.

Comment: The `date+extrayear` macro has been depreciated in favor of `date+extradate`. It probably makes sense to update the answer.

Answer (score 17):

UPDATE: A better solution for the bibliography may be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40710/510).

In-text-citations: Replace `\cite` with `\textcite`.

Bibliography: From my personal `biblatex.cfg` (plus `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`):

```
\makeatletter
\ifcsundef{abx@macro@\detokenize{date+extrayear}}{%
  }{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}{%
      }{%
      \addperiod\space
      \printtext{\printdateextra}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

(One could also simply redefine the `date+extrayear` bibmacro, but this would cause an error in case one switches to a style that doesn't feature this particular macro.)

EDIT: Alan Munn has brought my attention to the fact that my redefinition is based on an outdated version of `authoryear.bbx` which is by mistake still included in the biblatex version coming with MiKTeX. With a correctly installed biblatex version, my "solution" may or may not work for you.

EDIT 2: MiKTeX isn't the culprit. My preferred editor (TeXworks) somehow displays the contents of a former (!) version of `authoryear.bbx`.

EDIT 3: It seems that my redefinition will work with the default setting of the authoryear style, but is likely to break things if you tinker with the `mergedate` option (which was improved in biblatex v1.1b).

Comment: Thanks.  For (1) I should have RTFM better. For (2) this is the kind of thing that I never know where in the various parts of the `biblatex` code to look to find things like this.  I couldn't seem to find a definition like yours in `biblatex.def`, `authoryear.bbx` or `biblatex.sty`. This makes `biblatex` hacking quite frustrating.

Comment: @Alan: In fact, you missed it in `authoryear.bbx`. I agree that biblatex necessitates a STFF (scan the f*** files) approach.

Comment: to make this work with more recent versions of authoryear, I had to replace "extrayear" with "extradate". In the authoryear.cbx on my system there was a deprecation warning, so glad this hack works again with that thing changed.

Answer (score 11):

The following answer to the second part of my question is based on discussions with [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) in chat where we discovered that there have been significant changes to how dates are formatted in `bibtex` v1.1b which make his original answer potentially problematic. I thank him for his help.

For the first part of the question, his answer stands: to get parentheses around in-text citation years, use the `\textcite` family of commands.

To remove the parentheses from the bibliography years requires significant modification to the `.bbx` file. (I describe the modifications schematically here.) The actual modification should ideally be part of a separate `.bbx` file.

The biblatex `authoryear.bbx` file contains the following code to format various date fields.  (This is just one of 5 such blocks of code: `\bbx@opt@mergedate@maximum`, `compact`, `basic`, `minimum` and `false`.)

```
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@basic{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{labelyear}%
     \printfield{extrayear}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{date}{%
    \iffieldundef{month}
      {}
      {\printdate}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{month}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printdate}}%
    \newunit}%
}
```

The relevant part of the code that formats the year field is:

```
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{labelyear}%
     \printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

Notice that the two `\printfield` commands are enclosed in a `\printtext[parens]` command.  This is the command that needs to be changed.  So we redefine it without the `[parens]` format, and additionally we add punctuation and a space (which will appear right after the author name). This is needed because in styles that don't parenthesize the year, both author and year need to be punctuated.

So the redefined code is:

```
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\printtext{%
     \addperiod\space\printfield{labelyear}%
     \printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

The same change needs to be made in each of the `\bbx@opt@mergedate@...` commands.

To make these changes take effect, the `.bbx` file must also have the line:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelyear,sorting=nyt,pagetracker,mergedate}
```

Additionally, the following needs to be added to the `.bbx` file to correctly format the extra year field when the year is non-numeric. (Based on lockstep's answer to this question: [How to format the extrayear field in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11666/how-to-format-the-extrayear-field-in-biblatex).

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}{%
    \mknumalph{#1}%
  }{%
    \mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

It would be nice if this sort of change would not take such low-level programming, but could be a user option.  But for now this seems to be the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 6):

The `natbib` package has option `\citealt{...}` and `citealp{...}` (amongst others), which remove parentheses for in-text citations.

There is a great reference sheet that describes the [suppressed parenthesis methods](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php).

Copied from the above reference sheet:

```
\citealt{jon90}         -->     Jones et al. 1990
\citealt*{jon90}        -->     Jones, Baker, and Williams 1990
\citealp{jon90}         -->     Jones et al., 1990
\citealp*{jon90}        -->     Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990
\citealp{jon90,jam91}   -->     Jones et al., 1990; James et al., 1991
\citealp[pg. 32]{jon90} -->     Jones et al., 1990, pg. 32
\citetext{priv. comm.}  -->     (priv. comm.)
```

Though this does not directly answer what you appear to be after in the question, I found this question when looking for in-text citation methods, and thought I'd share it for others looking for the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you have parenthesis only around years, there is even a simpler way, by redefining the parenthesis punctuation. For instance, if you want the year enclosed in commas instead of parenthesis, you can have:

```
\renewcommand{\bibopenparen}{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand{\bibcloseparen}{\addcomma\addspace}
```

But note that this may mess up, if there are other parenthesis in the bibliography and/or citations.