# biblatex authoryear-icomp: How to change parenthesis to [asdf 1985]

Tags: biblatex, brackets

Sadly I didn't find any solutions in the biblatex doku nor in google.

Can anybody please point me out how to change the parenthesis of the authoryear-icomp (or authoryear style) from (author year) to [author year] (or recommend me another style providing that; I want to have my citations in the text in the form [author1 and author 2 year] respectively  [author1 et al. year]; & instead of and would be even better)

P.S.: Does anybody know a site where I can see (I only find the styles not a printout) the different styles in comparison? Testing all of these is quite a bit of work.

Comment: An example document for each standard style can be found in the `doc\latex\biblatex\examples` folder of your (la)tex installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For citations see Audrey's answer to [Biblatex, author-year, square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets).

For the bibliography, brackets instead of braces around the year can be achieved as follows (Note: This is very similar to my accepted answer to [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% By courtesy of Enrico Gregorio (egreg)
\makeatletter
\def\act@on@bibmacro#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
}
\def\patchbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\patchcmd}
\def\pretobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\pretocmd}
\def\apptobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\apptocmd}
\def\showbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\show}
\makeatother

\patchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \printtext[brackets]%
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

With regard to replacing "and" with "&": Search this site (or the `biblatex` manual) for `\multinamedelim` and `\finalnamedelim`.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm 8-) Thanks a lot! BTW I hoped it is easier to just change a bracket. Biblatex turns out to be quite complicated also. But to be honest: Id never go back to plain bibtex horros ;-) (besides for journal publications). BTW2 I am fine with how it turns out to be in the bibliography. Just wanted have a diffference between cites and remarks...

Comment: @louiscypher For different formatting of citations and the bibliography, use `\AtBeginBibliography`.

Comment: what to do if I want the bibliography style to appear as `[Auth year]` as well?

Comment: As of the current version of biblatex, `date+extrayear` is deprecated and `date+extradate` should be patched instead, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ef1661ca828f86bdc771c6ca3f3c55ea023760c9/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear.bbx#L22