# biblatex: How to omit "p." at \cite?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using `\cite[1]{A01}`. The result is

> Author 2001, p. 1

The desired result is

> Author 2001, 1

How do I achieve that? I'm aware of [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style), [biblatex authoryear-icomp: How to change parenthesis to [asdf 1985]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41866/biblatex-authoryear-icomp-how-to-change-parenthesis-to-asdf-1985), and [Biblatex, author-year, square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets) but they're not exactly my issue.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[1]{A01}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I usually use '\cite[{}1]{A01}'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To omit the page prefix for all citations, add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
```

(Actually, this is part of my rather verbose answer to [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).)

To suppress the prefix for individual citations, use `\nopp` within the citation's optional argument (thanks to Gonzalo Medina for the tip):

```
\cite[\nopp 1]{A01}
```

Conversely, you may force single page prefixes with `\pno` and range prefixes with `\ppno` (note the unbreakable space after these commands):

```
\cite[\pno~1]{A01}
\cite[\ppno~1--4]{A01}
```

See sections 3.7.8 and 3.12.3 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

Comment: I just used your comprehensive answer you referred to in the post, and this contained the additional line: `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the pages field in the bibliography`. Otherwise the two lines alone didn´t work for me to achieve the desired result