# How to change page display with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, german

I am using `biblatex` with `style=authoryear-icomp` and German settings. My citation show like this: `(Thomas 2011b, S. 143)`

I just want to change the `S.` (for page) with `:`, thus it would read: `(Thomas 2011b:143)`.

How to do so?

Here is my setup:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
```

Comment: Use `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}` plus my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53050/biblatex-how-to-omit-p-at-cite.

Answer (score 0):

you need to redefine the "Seite" field I guess as follows (to be tried because it may be wrong):

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
    Seite = {:},
    Seiten = {:}
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `page` and `pages`;-)

Comment: Yes, it's `page` and `pages` and it's only part of the answer. You still have to omit the comma before as explained in the other answer.