# Correct output format of page number using \cite command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am using biblatex, style=ieee, to create my bibliography.

In text I want the following cite with page number to look like this `[1:123]`, but all online resources seem to insist that I should use `\cite[p.~123]{keyword}` giving the output `[1, p. 123]`. How do I get the format I want?

**Edit**

To make clear what my code looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is a very nice introduction \cite[123]{Ref1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my .bib file looks like this

```
@book{Ref1,
address = {North pole},
author = {Ann Author},
edition = {1},
publisher = {Name},
title = {{This is a very nice title}},
year = {2017}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Usually it is best to provide a minimal document demonstrating your set-up.  In this case, you should be precise about how you load the `biblatex` package.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the tip. I have added that now.

Comment: Note that for `biblatex` the online resources you consulted have it wrong. You should normally use `\cite[123]{sigfridsson}` (i.e. no manual `p.~`) and then use `biblatex` options to control whether you automatically want to add 'p.' or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
```

we tell `biblatex` to use a colon between citation label and postnote, and to drop the 'p.' in postnotes.

So  `\cite[123]{sigfridsson}` results in

> [1:123]

Comment: Related: [How to change page display with biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103917/35864), [biblatex: How to omit “p.” at \cite?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53050/35864), [Colon instead of “p.” in Biblatex authoryear-comp](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66394/35864)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\nopp` option. E.g. `\cite[\nopp 123]{key}`

Check Section 3.13.3 of [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for more details.

Comment: This doesn't do quite what I was hoping for. \nopp only suppresses the p. in [1, p. 123]. I wanted [1:123]. I realise though that this may be more complicated than a simple option.

Comment: To make it clear, you get [1,123] and want [1:123] instead?

Comment: Yes. Also there is an extra space there I would like to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa:#2\fi}]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite[123]{xxx}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{xxx} xxx
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am creating the bibliography using the \printbibliography command and a .bib file. However, I used line 1-6 and it had no visible effect.

Comment: Please elaborate on what this does.

Comment: @Werner When I copy the entire code into a separate Latex file it works really well. However, when attempting to use only lines 1-6 along with `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` nothing happens.

Comment: @Tja...: It's important that you've identified using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) here. That's the difference.

Comment: @Werner Yeah I realised it was probably something like that. I should have been more precise when I asked the question