# Always suppress the "p." citation's prefix, but just for a specific book

Tags: biblatex, citing

I cite the answer from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53055/209996):

> To omit the page prefix for all citations, add the following to your
> preamble:
>
> ```
> \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
> \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
> ```

I would like to do exactly the same thing, but just for one specific book (so for all other books "p." should appear in the citation).

The same answer says that

> To suppress the prefix for individual citations, use \nopp within the
> citation's optional argument (thanks to Gonzalo Medina for the tip):
>
> ```
> \cite[\nopp 1]{A01}
> ```

The result is exactly what I want, but I would prefer not to have to write the command every time I quote that specific book, but to automate the operation.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pagination` field and give it the value `none` to suppress the page prefix.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  title      = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year       = {1972},
  publisher  = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location   = {London},
  pagination = {none},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[12]{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380) ipsum (Elk 1972, 12)]

If you also need to remove the comma in that case you can use something like

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
              and test {\iffieldequalstr{pagination}{none}}}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}%
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Do you also know how to remove the comma between the author-year and the page number? So, instead of `Elk 1972, 12`, i would like to get `Elk 1972 12` (but just for this book). Thanks in advance

Comment: @Urel See the update, please.