# How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?

Tags: biblatex

Some time ago, Alan Munn asked and lockstep eloquently answered [a question about removing parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style) from biblatex `authoryear` style references. Unfortunately, lockstep's solution injects an unwanted `\addperiod\space` into "dash" references.  For example, given Author, A. cited twice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Alpha}}
@misc{A02,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Beta}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \addperiod\space%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

we get:

[image]

I've tried building a solution using constructs like `\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}` without success. How, then, based on lockstep's nice `xpatch`-based approach, can I conditionally include `\addperiod\space` only in the case of "non-dash" references?

Comment: Comment the line `\addperiod\space%` and should work.

Comment: @Marco, no. As in Alan's original question and in lockstep's answer, the `\addperiod\space` is required after the `author` field in normal (non-repeated author, "non-dash") cases. To see this more clearly, change the `author=` field from `{Author, A.}` to, say, `{Author, Anne}`. In which case, we want output to look like `Author, Anne. 2001a` and `-- 2001b`. Commenting out the `\addperiod\space` produces `Author, Anne 2001a`. The question is, how can we *conditionally* remove the period in the repeated author ("dash") case?

Comment: I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output of units should be done inside the command `\setunit`.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution no longer works, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157390/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style-v