# How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v2)

Tags: biblatex

I have the same question as asked in [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67661/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style). The accepted answer, however, no longer works (presumable due to some update to `biblatex`). What would the current solution be?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Alpha}}
@misc{A02,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Beta}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can compile your file and the patch works fine.

Comment: @Bernard Maybe different versions? I see the same problem as Sverre when I compile that code.

Comment: @cfr I use the last version: biblatex 2.8a (MiKTeX 2.9).

Comment: To remove the parenthesis and add a period+space after the year, you can use `\DeclareFieldFormat*{parens}{#1\addperiod\addspace}`. However, I think it will format every fields in the bibliographic entry that are in parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

with

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Alpha}}
@misc{A02,author={Author, A.},year={2001},title={Beta}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I actually tried this already - but this will remove the period placed after an author's name (before the year).

Comment: @Sverre Are you saying that my MWE gives a different result to you?

Comment: No, the period remains in the MWE because the input happens to have "A." with a period in the ``.bib`` file (I just copied the example from the original to preserve consistency - maybe I shouldn't have). If this were e.g. "Author, Anne", it would give "Author, Anne 2001a." without a period, rather than "Author, Anne. 2001a."

Comment: @Sverre Note that there is no period between the author and the year in the normal behavior.

Comment: True, but that's because the "normal behavior" puts the year in parentheses. If the bibliography style doesn't use parentheses, there should be a period. That's why the original solution had the ``\addperiod`` command there.

Comment: @Sverre Now it should be like you wanted.

Comment: Interesting. Could you say in short what ``\setunit*{}`` does that makes this work?

Comment: @Sverre From the manual: The starred variant differs from the regular version in that it checks if the last `\printtext`, `\printfield`, `\printlist`, `\printnames`, or `\bibstring` command did actually print anything. If not, it does nothing.

Comment: The MWE is not working for me with biber 2.10 and texlive 2017.44590

Comment: With recent versions of `biblatex` you need to patch `date+extradate` since `date+extrayear` is deprecated.