# Add period after dashed authors, but comma after dashed editors (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, biber, xpatch

First I remove the parentheses around the year in the bibliography and add a period after the entry name with:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}{}{}
```

(from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158481/9077)).

Then I add a period after the dash for dashed entries with:

```
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\addperiod\space}
```

This looks fine when the dashed entry is an author (see McCartney in the MWE below), but it looks wrong for dashed editors. Instead of

> ------. Ed. 1966. *More songs I like*.

It should be

> ------, ed. 1966. *More songs I like*.

In effect, the dash should only replace the repeated name, and change nothing else. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1965,
    EDITOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Old songs I like",
    YEAR = "1965"}
@book{lennon1966,
    EDITOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More old songs I like",
    YEAR = "1966"}
@book{mccartney1965,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "This is what I did yesterday",
    YEAR = "1965"}
@book{mccartney1966,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "My troubles don't seem so far away",
    YEAR = "1966"}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}{}{} % remove parenthesis around year in bibliography
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\addperiod\space} % use a 3em dash with period after it for dashed author names

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker.

```
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{%
  \printtext{%
    \rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
```

That way we print the name dash and afterwards use the punctuation tracker to sort things out for us.

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1965,
    EDITOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Old songs I like",
    YEAR = "1965"}
@book{lennon1966,
    EDITOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More old songs I like",
    YEAR = "1966"}
@book{mccartney1965,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "This is what I did yesterday",
    YEAR = "1965"}
@book{mccartney1966,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "My troubles don't seem so far away",
    YEAR = "1966"}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
  \xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}{}{}
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\printtext{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}}\setunit{\addcomma\space}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we get

[image: correctly-dashed bibliography]