# How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)

Tags: biblatex

I have a question that has been answered a few times, but does not work for me (and also not for another commenter in a previously asked question).

I want to remove the parenthesis around the yead in the bibliography with biblatex style authoryear, and ideally also add a comma and space before it. I have looked at the following questions:

[biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style)

[How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67661/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style)

[How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157390/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style-v/158481#158481?newreg=db4f855475dc42888b5993e38792a960)

I use `biber` 2.10 and TexLive 2017/W32Tex.

This MWE should work according to the question v2 above, but does not work for me, i.e. the output is still `Author, Anne (2001a). Alpha.` The output I need is `Author, Anne, 2001a. Alpha.`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,author={Author, Anne},year={2001},title={Alpha}}
@misc{A02,author={Author, Anne},year={2001},title={Beta}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bibmacro `date+extrayear` is deprecated, and is replaced with `date+extradate`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,author={Author, Anne},year={2001},title={Alpha}}
@misc{A02,author={Author, Anne},year={2001},title={Beta}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Oops, I was a tad too slow. (+1) (But the OP asks for a comma between the name and the year.)

Comment: @gusbrs I'll fix that.

Comment: The macro in question was renamed in `biblatex` v3.8 (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki#release-notes-for-version-38 and in particular https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Name-Changes). These 'renaming sprees' should ideally be kept at a minimum and in hindsight changing the macro names might have been worse than living with the apparent slight inconsistency between macro name and field name. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/700

Comment: This solution appears not to work anymore. I've opened a question about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646296/9077).

Comment: @Sverre It *does* work... if you read it more carefully.  ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs You're right! And I've deleted my new question, as it didn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Allow me to indulge in a bit of advertising for [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext). The `ext-authoryear` family has built-in support to change the format of the year. The `ext-...` styles are compatible with the standard styles and can be used as a drop-in replacement.

You just need to redefine the field format `biblabeldate` (a `biblatex-ext` feature) and the delimiter `nameyeardelim` (a standard `biblatex` feature) appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]