# Change biblatex bibliography display to conform Astrophysics Journal Specs by removing year from parentheses

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have combed through previous questions for some time, and have not yet found any answers to my specific questions.  So I am now hoping that someone here can help me out

I am finishing a up an article to be submitted to the Astrophysics Journal (ApJ), which has some pretty specific formatting instructions (see [here](https://journals.aas.org/authors/manuscript.html)).  I am in particular trying to get the bibliography to format properly using the biblatex package.  The ApJ bibliography formatting instructions ([here](https://journals.aas.org/authors/references.html)) tell you that articles should be cited as:

> author1_last, author1_first_init. author1_middle_init., author2_last,
>   author2_first_init. author2_middle_init., author3_last,
>   author3_first_init. author3_middle_init., & author4_last,
>   author4_first_init. author4_middle_init. YEAR, JournalName, Volume
>   number, first page

or as

> author1_last, author1_first_init. author1_middle_init., author2_last,
>   author2_first_init. author2_middle_init., author3_last,
>   author3_first_init. author3_middle_init., et al. YEAR, JournalName,
>   Volume number, first page

For example, the following bibliographic entries:

```
@article{Bennett93,
author = {Bennet, C. L. and N. W. Boggess and E. S. Cheng and M. G. Hauser and  T. Kelsall and J. C. Mather and S. H. Moseley, Jr.
          and T. L. Murdock and R. A. Shafer and R. F. Silverberg and G. F. Smoot and R. Weissi and E. L. Wright},
title = {Scientific Results from COBE},
journal = {AdSpR},
volume = {13},
number = {12},
year = {1993}
}

@article{Gupta08,
author = {Gupta, Shashikant and Saini, Tarun Deep and Laskar, Tanmoy},
title = {Direction dependence and non-Gaussianity in the high-redshift supernova data},
journal = {MNRAS},
volume = {388},
number = {1},
pages = {242-246},
year = {2008},
doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2008.13377.x},
URL = { + http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2966.2008.13377.x},
eprint = {/oup/backfile/content_public/journal/mnras/388/1/10.1111_j.1365-2966.2008.13377.x/2/mnras0388-0242.pdf}
}
```

Should yield the following bibliography entries:

> Bennet, C. L. et al. 1993, AdSpR 13, 409
>
> Gupta, S., Saini, T. D., & Laskar, T. 2008, MNRAS 388, 242

By searching previous, similar questions, I have managed to get my biblatex file to yield something close, but not quite right:

> Bennet, C. L. et al. (1993). AdSpR 13, 409
>
> Gupta, S., Saini, T. D., & Laskar, T. (2008). MNRAS 388, 242

So I need to make the following changes:

(1) Year should not be in parentheses

(2) There should be a comma after year, rather than a period

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[minnames=1,maxnames=1,maxbibnames = 5, style=authoryear, bibstyle = authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, block = none, isbn = false, url = false, doi = false, eprint = false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{ }
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\addbibresource{mwe_refs.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}% 
  \newunit}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{document} 
Here is the first reference \parencite{Bennett93}.
And here is the second reference \parencite{Gupta08}.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Where mwe_refs.bib is a text file in the same directory with the Gupta and Bennet references mentioned above.

Output screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if any additional clarification is needed.

-Sasha

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190). (I would use moewe's answer rather than mine, even though mine is the accepted one.)

Comment: [You probably don't want to hear it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7711/35864), but you should probably not be using `biblatex` for your submission to the AAS. The page you link to states "Authors are strongly encouraged to prepare their manuscripts using the most recent version of the AASTeX macro package [...]." https://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasguide.html#citations suggests either a manual `thebibliography` or `natbib`. In the latter case "Authors should use the new aasjournal.bst file when using BibTex with AAS Journal manuscripts."

Comment: [Many journals can't handle `biblatex` submissions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) and the quotes on the AAS page make me suspect that they would really, really prefer it if you used either a manual `thebibliography` or their `aasjournal.bst`.

Comment: That said, my answer in Alan's link together with `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}` and I presume `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}` (or maybe `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`) should solve the two things you ask for.

Comment: Hi all.  Thanks for the advice, both on the details of the question and the broader observations that perhaps biblatex may not be the way to go for this task.  I have so far had difficulty getting aasjournal.bst to work effectively with the rest of the document, but perhaps I should revisit that.  Any way, thanks for the help.

Comment: Belated self-promotion: I made a `biblatex` style for ApJ (https://github.com/EdwinChan/biblatex-apj). I use it internally when writing but it's easy to switch back to `natbib` when submitting by turning on `natbib` compatibility in `biblatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the parenthesis is covered by [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/15925)

To fix the punctuation, you can change the `\newunitpunct`:

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Combining these two fixes we get:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[minnames=1,maxnames=1,maxbibnames = 5, style=authoryear, bibstyle = authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, block = none, isbn = false, url = false, doi = false, eprint = false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{ }
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\addbibresource{mwe_refs.bib}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{document}
Here is the first reference \parencite{Bennett93}.
And here is the second reference \parencite{Gupta08}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Many thanks, and I apologize for the partial duplication.

Answer (score 3):

The [AAS manuscript preparation guidelines](https://journals.aas.org/authors/manuscript.html#_Toc2.1) strongly encourage authors to use the AASTeX class

> Authors are strongly encouraged to prepare their manuscripts using the most recent version of the AASTeX macro package, and to submit them electronically.

The [AASTeX guide](https://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasguide.html#citations) lists several ways to create a bibliography

1. manual `thebibliography` or
2. `natbib` together with the `aasjournal.bst` style

   > Authors are also encouraged to use reference management software such as BibTex to organize their references and produce correct bibliographies. When using BibTeX a .bst file is need to produce the proper reference output that follows the AAS Journal's format. Authors should use the new `aasjournal.bst` file when using BibTex with AAS Journal manuscripts.

   or
3. a `references` environment

The guidelines also state

> They are the standard LaTeX `thebibliography` environment, and the AASTeX `references` environment. Authors are strongly encouraged to use `thebibliography`.

There is no reference to BibTeX in that passage and strictly speaking BibTeX produces `thebibliography`, so one might assume that use of BibTeX would also be fine. For submission a pasted `thebibliography` from the `.bbl` produced by BibTeX  with the correct `.bst` might be the best solution.

---

I strongly doubt that the AAS will be happy to accept a submission using `biblatex`. The workflow with `biblatex` and Biber is quite different from traditional BibTeX. See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)

It is not just a matter of producing the same PDF output. Many journals don't actually care about the PDF produced by TeX, they will convert submitted `.tex` into their favourite format. Using non-standard packages can make it much harder and might break the journal's workflow.

Especially if so detailed TeX submission guidelines are available you should have a very good reason not to follow the guidelines and use a bibliography system not listed there.

---

That all said here is a solution with `biblatex-ext`. Even if the chances that they can accept `biblatex` are slim, the chances they'll like `biblatex-ext` are about non-existent. `biblatex-ext` is a very new style bundle available since spring this year (so TeX live < 2018 won't have it) and publishers are not known to be update aficionados.

It doesn't cover all of https://journals.aas.org/authors/references.html perfectly, but it should be a start and should give correct results for `@article`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, isbn = false, url = false, doi = false, eprint = false, minnames=1,maxnames=1,maxbibnames = 5, date=year, articlein=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{book}{}{\clearfield{title}}%
  \clearfield{number}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iflistundef{location}} or not test {\iflistundef{#1}}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printlist{location}%
       \iflistundef{#1}
         {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
         {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
       \printlist{#1}%
       \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bennett93,
author = {Bennet, C. L. and N. W. Boggess and E. S. Cheng and M. G. Hauser and  T. Kelsall and J. C. Mather and S. H. Moseley, Jr.
          and T. L. Murdock and R. A. Shafer and R. F. Silverberg and G. F. Smoot and R. Weissi and E. L. Wright},
title = {Scientific Results from COBE},
journal = {AdSpR},
volume = {13},
number = {12},
year = {1993}
}

@article{Gupta08,
author = {Gupta, Shashikant and Saini, Tarun Deep and Laskar, Tanmoy},
title = {Direction dependence and non-Gaussianity in the high-redshift supernova data},
journal = {MNRAS},
volume = {388},
number = {1},
pages = {242-246},
year = {2008},
doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2008.13377.x},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,Bennett93,Gupta08}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Taking your advice, I (with some pain) managed to reformat my paper using the AASTeX class.  Thank you for your thoughts.