# Customization in biblatex citestyle and in bibliographystyle influencing each other

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I'm working with biblatex and need to fulfill the following requirements:

The citation should look like this:

- when there is one author: `<lastname1> <year>`
- when there are two authors: `<lastname1> and <lastname2> <year>`
- when there are more than two authors: `<lastname1> et al. <year>`

The bibliography should look like this:

`<lastname>, <f>; <lastname>, <f>; <lastname>, <f>; <year> : Title. …`
(f = initial letter of firstname)

Until now, I have customized the style authoryear as follows:

authoryear-ing.cbx:

```
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-ing.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear-comp}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
andothers     = {et\,al\adddot}
}

\endinput
```

authoryear-ing.bbx:

```
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-ing.bbx}

\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

% Redefining the separator between author-names
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}

% Redefining the separator between the last two author-names
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}


% Redefining the separator between author-names  / editor-names and year in bibliography(not working yet)
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}
          {\setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}}%
     {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}}%
     \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}


% firstname is displayed after the lastname
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% no parenthesis
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\printdateextralabel}%
      {\printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}%

\endinput
```

My document looks like this:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, ngerman, bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=numbered, 12pt]{scrartcl}

%% Codierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

%% Biblatex
\usepackage[
backend = biber, 
sorting = nyt, 
citestyle = authoryear-ing, 
bibstyle = authoryear-ing,
maxcitenames = 2,
mincitenames = 1, 
maxbibnames = 100,
minbibnames = 100,
firstinits = true,
abbreviate = true
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@book{buch1,
    Author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins and Vornamezwei Nachnahmezwei},
    Title = {Title},
    Year = {2010}}

@book{buch2,
    Author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins},
    Title = {Title},
    Year = {2015}}

@book{buch3,
    Author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins and Vornamezwei Nachnahmezwei and Vornamedrei Nachnahmedrei},
    Title = {Title},
    Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{buch1}\\
\cite{buch2}\\
\cite{buch3}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

It seems like the citestyle and the bibstyle are influencing each other. 
Is there a way to fulfill the requirements I mentioned above? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of `biblatex` are you using? (Add `\listfiles` to the beginning to your `.tex` file and check the list at the end of the `.log` file.)

Comment: I'm asking about your `biblatex` version because your code seems to be for an older version (`firstinits` was renamed to `giveninits` in version 3.3 released a bit more than three years ago now, 2016-03-01) and some of the things you want to do are much easier with features and functions introduced in newer `biblatex` versions. In particular `multinamedelim` and `finalnamdelim` can be controlled context-dependently now and the separators between author, year and title can also be changed much easier in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of `biblatex` there are many new functions and features that make your life much easier. Amongst other things `multinamedelim` and `finaldnamedelim` are now context sensitive which makes it easier to have different definitions for citations and the bibliography. Furthermore `nametitledelim` and `nameyeardelim` can help you get the colon after the year and the closing semicolon in the bibliography, respectively.

I have based my suggestion on `ext-authoryear-comp` (from my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)) because that allowed for a simpler way of getting rid of the parentheses around the year in the bibliography (cf. [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864)).

I have moved the load-time options to the relevant `.bbx` and `.cbx` files and have also added the `uniquelist` and `uniquename` options because I *think* you would want them to be different from the default. See for example [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864), [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864) and the `biblatex` documentation about the two options.

In the MWE I used `filecontents` to produce the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files as well. **Warning:** Since the `filecontents` package is loaded `authoryear-ing.bbx` and `authoryear-ing.cbx` as well as the `.bib` file will be overwritten without prior notice or interaction. Test this MWE in a new and empty folder to avoid losing your precious work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman, bibliography=totocnumbered, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{authoryear-ing.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-ing.bbx}

\RequireBibliographyStyle{ext-authoryear-comp}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  maxbibnames = 100,
  minbibnames = 100,
  giveninits = true,
  abbreviate = true,
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{nameyeardelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}


\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{authoryear-ing.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-ing.cbx}

\RequireCitationStyle{ext-authoryear-comp}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  maxcitenames = 2,
  mincitenames = 1,
  uniquelist   = false,
  uniquename   = init,
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers     = {et\,al\adddot}
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend = biber, 
  style = authoryear-ing, 
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{buch1,
  author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins and Vornamezwei Nachnahmezwei},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {2010},
}
@book{buch2,
  author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {2015},
}
@book{buch3,
  author = {Vornameeins Nachnahmeeins and Vornamezwei Nachnahmezwei
            and Vornamedrei Nachnahmedrei},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{buch1}

\cite{buch2}

\cite{buch3}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Nachnahmeeins und Nachnahmezwei 2010//Nachnahmeeins 2015//Nachnahmeeins et al. 2010" in the citations. "Nachnahmeeins, V.; 2015: Title.//Nachnahmeeins, V.; Nachnahmezwei, V.; 2010: Title.//Nachnahmeeins, V.; Nachnahmezwei, V.; Nachnahmedrei, V.; 2010: Title." in the bibliography.]