How to create a custom `.bbx` file to extend a default BibLaTeX style?
I am using BibLaTeX for my bibliography management and would like to create a custom .bbx file that extends the default predefined style without modifying it. For example, I want to add support for a new entry type, e.g., @bachelorthesis, that resembles @mastersthesis.
How can I create a custom .bbx file to achieve this? How do I ensure that my custom style file extends the default style properly?
P.S. I know this solution and used the @bachelorthesis as an example. The goal is to learn how to extend the types without changing the default .bbx file. I want to know how to create a new .bbx file to extend the default types and place it somewhere locally in my project root.

Have a look at the bbx styles which come with biblatex, for example the numeric-comp.bbx loads the numeric.bbx style. You could use such an approach as a basis for any extension you'd like to make.

Just for people looking for @bachelorthesis: The biblatex solution here would be to use @thesis and add type = {bathesis}, to the entry.

You don't always have to create a new .bbx file. Sometimes it's easier to just put a couple of lines into the preamble: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864. But there is definitely a point where a new .bbx (and .cbx) comes in handy.

Some comments can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426387/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864. A couple examples are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480072/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427671/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427231/35864.

Generally speaking you'll have a \RequireBibliographyStyle{<base style>} at the beginning of your .bbx that loads the (base) style you want to modify. Afterwards you just add the new code you want. There is almost no technical way to make sure your modifications are done properly (save for a couple of warnings by \newbibmacro and friends), you have to read the code of the base style carefully and code your modifications accordingly.

@moewe, thanks for the research. Would it be possible to compile those posts and comments into one concise answer here? For example, a template .bbx file, where it should be placed, how it could be loaded in the preamble of the .tex file...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am using overleaf.com at the moment, and I think more people do that. As explained in the post, I could try to dig further into my local installation, but I want to avoid that.

You can view the files on ctan if you don't want to look them up in your local installation: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/bbx

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz OK, so in this case numeric-comp.bbx extends numeric.bbx?

@Foad yes ("extents" in the sense that it uses it as base style, but does not actually add anything new - but it could add stuff)

You don't always have to create a new style with .bbx and .cbx files if you want to modify the bibliography/citation output in your document. For one-off modifications it is often easier to just put a couple of lines into the preamble and there are other options (Biblatex.cfg vs .cls vs .sty). But there is definitely a point where a new .bbx (and/or .cbx) comes in handy.
You can find more discussions about how to start writing a new style at Custom Style breaks the "cite" command and Customizing a biblatex style - can I start with lockstep's post?. Generally speaking, you can either build upon an existing style (via biblatex's means) or code a completely new style (possibly using a lot of copy-and-paste from existing styles).
If you've decided you want to modify an existing style, you need to familiarise yourself with its code (What is the location of the biblatex citation style files?) and will then create two new files loading the base style. For the start it would be easiest to just create these two files in the same directory as your main .tex file, since they will then be found without further ado. If you've written your style and want to make it available to all your documents later on, you may want to have a look at Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files? (note that this does not easily carry over to Overleaf, but on Overleaf you can share files between projects).
You'd have a file biblatex-foad.bbx containing
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-foad.bbx}[2024/06/05 v0.1 Foad's bibliography style]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{<base bib style>}

\endinput

and a biblatex-foad.cbx containing
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-foad.cbx}[2024/06/05 v0.1 Foad's citation style]

\RequireCitationStyle{<base cite style>}

\endinput

You can then add your modifications before \endinput (the command is not strictly needed, but the standard biblatex style use it, so there's that).
There is almost no technical way to ensure that your modifications are "done properly", you have to read the code of the base style carefully and code your modifications accordingly.
The style would then be loaded as
\usepackage[style=biblatex-foad]{biblatex}

in your document preamble.
This is assuming your write a style consisting of both a .bbx and .cbx file. If you only write one of the two (say the .bbx), then you would say something like
\usepackage[bibstyle=biblatex-foad, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

You can read more about the process at Custom Style breaks the "cite" command and Customizing a biblatex style - can I start with lockstep's post? and see a couple of real-world examples at Formatting issue with DeclareBibliographyDriver in my Custom Biblatex Style based, Creating a custom biblatex using existing field and changing the formatting and Customization in biblatex citestyle and in bibliographystyle influencing each other.
A great first resource for style modifications is Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles, but you will find many, many questions and answers on this site about specific problems.
