# Make the author names, the year, and the journal's volume number bold with biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style

I'm using biber with the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

At the end of my tex document, I print the reference list:

```
\printbibliography[title={References}]
```

The journal editor required me to change the reference list such that the author names, the year, and the journal's volume number are bold. I couldn't find a clear way to do this. Is this possible? If so, any clue on how to do it?

Comment: It should be possible. Could you post a complete, yet minimal, code that we can play with?

Comment: This isn't too hard to do. But the standard `authoryear` style formats the volume and issue number as `vol.iss` (e.g. 14.3). So do you want only the volume bold, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `biblatex-ext` styles (which provide drop-in replacements for the standard styles), we can easiy customize both the names the date format. (See [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/2693)).  Thanks to moewe for pointing out the simpler name code too (and for writing `biblatex-ext`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\mkbibparens{\mkbibbold{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
\autocite{herrmann,doody}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of biblatex-ext code]

If you want to do this using the `apa` style (which I don't recommend) the following code needs to be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareNameFormat{apaauthor}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\maxprtauth\AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
    {\addcomma\addspace\ldots\addspace}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth\AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
      {}
      {\iffieldannotation{uncertain}
        {\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{name:apa:family-given}%
                         {\namepartfamily}%
                         {\namepartgiven}%
                         {\namepartgiveni}%
                         {\namepartprefix}%
                         {\namepartsuffix}?}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:apa:family-given}%
          {\namepartfamily}%
          {\namepartgiven}%
          {\namepartgiveni}%
          {\namepartprefix}%
          {\namepartsuffix}}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{listtotal}}%
      {\ifmorenames{\printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{andothers}}{}}{}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{apadate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdatecirca} or test {\ifdateuncertain} }
    {\printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\mkbibbold{#1}}}}
    {\printtext{\mkbibparens{\mkbibbold{#1}}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}




\begin{document}
\autocite{herrmann,doody}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of APA code]

Comment: Thanks. Same here, I couldn't get the dates in bold. Strange.

Comment: @hsnm Your example used `authoryear` as the style. If you are using `apa` as the style, then the question is a lot different. `apa` is a complex style that is not designed to be modified, since it implements the very specific APA requirements.

Comment: Changing the date did not work in authoryear.

Comment: @hsnm You need to load `ext-authoryear` not `authoryear`.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but my compiler didn't find ext-authoryear.

Comment: @hsnm It's a fairly recent addition, released in 2018. If you can, it might make sense to update your distribution.

Comment: +1 For `biblatex-ext` ;-)  With `\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}` you can avoid the new name format `family-given-bold`.

Comment: @moewe Even better! But I think that should be `\DeclareNameAlias` not `\DelareNameFormat`?

Comment: So it should be, sorry. (I even ran the code and didn't realise all names came out literally as "family-given" ...)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add some code to change the wanted author names, year and volume number to be bold (see marking `<=====` for important code with explanaition for its use) in your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % <=========================== date 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % <===== volume
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-bold}{\mkbibbold{% <====================== name
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

So with the following complete mwe (please next time add one to your next question by your own -- it is then easier to help you!)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ahlswede2000network,
  title={Network information flow},
  author={Ahlswede, Rudolf and Cai, Ning and Li, Shuo-Yen Robert and 
          Yeung, Raymond W},
  journal={Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={1204--1216},
  year={2000},
  publisher={IEEE},
}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics",
}
@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=9,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false,
  autocite=inline
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % <=========================== date 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % <===== volume
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-bold}{\mkbibbold{% <====================== name
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}


\begin{document}

Some \autocite{einstein} text \cite{einstein}.
\parencite[I.6.2]{dirac}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Comment: The default author/year name format is Family-Given, not Given-Family.

Comment: @AlanMunn Intresting, I got no error message or warning, Not with `given-family`, nor with `family-given` or `Family-Given`, but always the same resulting bibliography. Bug or feature in `biblatex`?

Comment: You need to change the definition you've given to `first-last-bold`.

Comment: @AlanMunn ?? what should be changed? It compiles withour error message or warning on my current MiKTeX ...

Comment: Thanks. It works well, except that I had to use \DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\bfseries{#1}}  instead (no idea why). I tried your code with style=apa, but I did not get bold names, date, nor volume. What would be different with apa?