# Modify apa style in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm not well-versed with the complex looking constructs for modifying biblatex styles. The style I wish to use is,
[image]

APA is the closest I could find. I get the following on using it:
[image]

Please help me change this default APA style to the one above. Even some other route without APA is fine.

I looked up online and found the following MWE from a source (which I'm unable to find again) that would embolden the author names only in the references and not in the in-text citations. Though the initials weren't emboldened.

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{blah.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textbf{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

[image]

The edits to the style required:

- Full name in bold
- Name style: surname, initials or initials surname
- Year after author names
- Journal volume number in bold
- No 'In:' before the journal name

Comment: The `apa` style is not really designed to be modified, since it implements the conforming APA style. You would be better off starting with the `ext-authoryear` style and working from there. It seems that you want a basic author-year system in citations and bibliography  but with a numbered bibliography with bolded names. Is this correct?

Comment: Also the formats of your first two samples are contradictory: LastName, Initial vs Initial LastName. Or is the order supposed to switch for subsequent works by the same author? That's a really odd requirement.

Comment: On numbering author-year bibliographies see [How to get references with numbers in author-year style with biblatex?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/470700) (which is possibly where you got part of your code from.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, that is correct. Though by changing ```apa``` to ```ext-authoryear``` as is doesn't change anything and I don't know how to edit the style. The name style confused me as well but I'll go for LastName, Initial. The fact that my uni needs author-year style in-text citations and a numbered bibliography itself felt odd (can't help it). Can you help me edit ```ext-authoryear```? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,
            articlein=false,
            giveninits=true,
            uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470700/
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497426/
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
% Other modifications
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, Alan. You're a saviour. It works. I'm squeezed with a deadline, but asa I'm done with that, I'll try to understand the code.