# Customisation of Biblatex command

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have used `\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, uniquename=false]{biblatex}` command in my article. Now I need help to (i) delete the issue number of the referred journals (ii) make volume of the journal in references BOLD (iii) For multiple author names are joined by '&" symbol, want them to be 'and', however in .bib file its 'and'  but in the .tex file its showing symbol. I am using APA style

Comment: In future please only ask about one issue per question. That makes your question easier to answer and more useful for other people on this site as well. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `number` field with a sourcemap (see for example [Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864), [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864)). The `volume` can be formatted in bold by modifying the field format (cf. [Make the author names, the year, and the journal's volume number bold with biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497426/35864)).

For the "&" we need to modify the context-sensitive `finalnamedelim` delimiter.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset = number, null]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{\apanum{#1}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., and Ryde, U. (1998).]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. It worked well. Still need help as in reference before the start of 'and' of the last author the comma(,) needs to be omitted. Please help

Comment: @SangeetaNath Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670888/35864.

Comment: Your codes are perfectly working in my project. Please help to make the "et al." part of the citation in Italics. It is showing as straight text.

Comment: @SangeetaNath Again. That would be a new question. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644877/35864.