# BibLatex - Help with APA/Harvard

Tags: biblatex, macros, apa-style

Im using APA style in Biblatex and I want to know how I could remove the parantheses around year. I found code for this with authoryear, but nothing for APA. This is my code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa} %get year
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

...begin document...

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{} 
\printbibliography
\enddocument
```

PS: its for the thesis so I only added what I think is the relevant parts. Let me know if more is needed!

Comment: The `apa` style isn't really designed to be modified. Is there a reason why you're using it as opposed to `authoryear` (perhaps with some minor modifications)?  You might want to check out the `biblatex-ext` styles which allow easier modification of the basic styles.

Comment: @AlanMunn Only because it was the most similar one(I'm very new to biblatex!). Alright, nice I'll look more into modifying authoryear/biblatex-ext then, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` was specifically written to meet all the complex requirements of the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association. This means that it can be quite tricky to modify the style to deviate from its intended APA output.

As [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) [mentions in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503243/biblatex-help-with-apa-harvard#comment1271198_503243) it is usually better to use one of the standard styles or a style of the [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle as basis for a custom style than to modify `biblatex-apa`.

In this case there is a fairly simple solution, but you should not count on this in general.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{apadate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdatecirca} or test {\ifdateuncertain} }
    {\printtext{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\printtext{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P]

The answers in [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864) show how you would remove the parentheses for the standard styles and `biblatex-ext` (but judging from the code in the question *you* already know those ...).