# Use autocite=footnote with style=authoryear-ibid in biblatex and enclose only the year in parentheses

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I'm using the following configuration to cite sources:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

One of my indirect citations looks like this:

```
\autocite[Vgl.][123]{ruschmeyer}
```

I get this result:

> Vgl. Ruschmeyer u. a. 1995, S. 123

I'd rather like to get this result, according to my university's guidelines:

> Vgl. Ruschmeyer u. a. (1995), S. 123

How can I enclose the year in brackets and keep everything else as it is? I've read about `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand`, but it seems to do a lot more than what I need.

I had a look at [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style), but it does not work for indirect citations and the parentheses also include the pagenumbers.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to redefine the macro `cite:labelyear+extrayear` to always wrap the `labelyear` (and `extrayear`, if applicable) in parentheses.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```

This will make `\textcite` and `\citeyear` look weird though, so we can also go for a slightly longer redefinition of the `cite` macro (along with a definition of a new macro):

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear:paren}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\addspace}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear:paren}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

or (to put everything into one macro)

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\addspace}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
        \iffieldundef{labelyear}
          {}
          {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

MWE with the second solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear:paren}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\addspace}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear:paren}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[Vgl.][123]{markey} ipsum\autocite{knuth:ct:a} dolor\autocite{knuth:ct:b} sit\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} amet.

\Textcite{wilde} consecetur.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you. How can I figure something like that out on my own? I know how to print macro definitions (e.g. with `\meaning`), but how did you manage to get all that information?

Comment: @Tobias You're welcome. The definitions can be found in `biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx` as well as `<style>.bbx` and `<style>.cbx`, the macros here were hidden in `authoryear-ibid.cbx` (sometimes these files link to other ones via `\RequireCitationStyle`/`RequireBibliographyStyle`).

Comment: I'll have a look at that!

Comment: I tried to use this with the Bib-style `style=authoryear` and with `\footcite` instat of `\autocite`. This doesn't work for me. After deleting the line with: `\global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}` there are no errors produced anymore, but I don't know if this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Latex_NOOB As this answer was specifically tailored to `authoryear-ibid` it is not guaranteed to work with other styles, `authoryear` should be close enough, but you can run into trouble with certain macros or other things not being defined (`\global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}` did not work because `authoryear` does not know about the bool value `cbx:loccit`). Du to `biblatex`'s structure deleting this line should work, but the only way to really judge whether this is what you want is by looking at the output...

Comment: An awesome cut-and-paste solution that has really solved my issues - only request - is there any chance you could put in some commenting/psuedocode? Although relatively latex-proficient this still goes massively over my head!

Comment: @davidhood2 I don't think there is lots of commenting to be done. The redefinitions are copies of the original definitions with `\printtext[parens]{...}` added. Have a look at `authoryear-ibid.cbx` and compare the definitions. Note that the answer was based on an earlier version of `biblatex`. With the new `biblatex` 3.8a (just released), `cite:labelyear+extrayear` has a nicer definition and is in fact renamed to `cite:labeldate+extradate`. Let me know if you want me to update the solution.