# Reference style "MISQ"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am looking for a possibility to use the MISQ style for my references, which looks like this:

> Baskerville, R. L. and Myers, M. D. 2009. “Fashion Waves in Information Systems Research and Practice,” in MIS Quarterly (33:4), p. 647 (doi: 10.2307/20650319).

Currently my reference style looks like this:

[image]

This is how my code in LaTeX looks like:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
firstinits=true,
natbib=true,
url=true, 
doi=true,
eprint=false,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

So basically, I need to use "," instead of ".". I also need to get rid of the brackets around the year. And I need to display all other authors besides the first author in the same way as the first author: Last name, First names abbreviated. Also, I need brackets around the journal number and issue, and around the DOI.

Has anyone got an idea how to achieve this? Maybe someone trying to use the MISQ style found a way to use it in LaTeX?

Comment: Citing authors etc. is not [tag:cross-referencing]!

Answer (score 3):

A bit of googling turns up https://github.com/pcbouman-eur/misq-latex-style an unofficial LaTeX class. The README states

> As MISQ formally only accepts Word documents, use it is at your own risk. However, it is whispered that there are actually ways to submit PDF files for review purposes when you contact the editors.

So if you are looking to submit to MISQ, you may be out of luck using LaTeX.
If you only like the MISQ style or are confident you can get them to accept a TeX-typeset PDF you can start with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  giveninits=true,
  eprint=false,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addperiod\space}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addcolon}%
    \printfield{number}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    doi\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the original MISQ style guidelines (https://misq.org/manuscript-guidelines), the date / year shouldn't be in parentheses in the list of references. The following fix helps to remove them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40710/160825