# Remove parentheses at year biblatex with author year

Tags: biblatex, windows, macos

I'm trying to use `authoryear` style and remove the parentheses around the year:

> Authors...2018. Title...

instead of

> Authors...(2018) Title...

in the bibliography. I am, however, not able to get it to work. 
e.g.
[biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style/147537)
fails. `biblatex-chicago` also fails.
I found that in newer versions, the macro has to be changed adding a *. My new MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
\printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which consequently fails too:

[image]

I tested `pdflatex`, `lualatex` on macOS and Windows. Packages are up to date. Can someone help?

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate. If the answer in the duplicate does for some reason not work for you, please edit your question, explain how and share more details about your package versions (upload the relevant parts of the `.log` file). In that case I will immediately vote to reopen this question.

Comment: That one was my question, I thin something went wrong here. However, the solution provided does work. Thank you

Comment: I thought you referred to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12254/35864? I closed as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864 (a different question with similar title), where one of the answers is exactly what SrongBad suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in `authoryear.bbx`

```
\providebibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \blx@warning{bibmacro 'date+extrayear' is deprecated.\MessageBreak
    Please use 'date+extradate'.\MessageBreak
    Using 'date+extradate' instead}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
```

You just need to change

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
```

to

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
```